# How to parse the date value into SonarAPI call

Tags: json, powershell, api, sonarqube

From one of the SonarAPI Call, got the value of date as `2018-12-13T18:04:42-0500`,

now when try to parse this date value to SonarAPI its failing with below error:

```
 Invoke-RestMethod : {
  "errors": [
    {
      "msg": "Date '$date' cannot be parsed as either a date or date+time"
    }
  ]
}
```

When the below URL is browsed on browser:

```
https://xxx.xxx.xxxx/api/measures/search_history?component=AP-EASI&metrics=coverage&from=2018-12-13T18:04:42-0500&to=2018-12-13T18:04:42-0500
```

the output on browser is:

```
{
  "paging": {
    "pageIndex": 1,
    "pageSize": 100,
    "total": 1
  },
  "measures": [
    {
      "metric": "coverage",
      "history": [
        {
          "date": "2018-12-13T18:04:42-0500",
          "value": "0.0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
$date = "2018-12-13T18:04:42-0500"
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/measures/search_history?component=AP-EASI&metrics=coverage&from=$date&to=$date' -Headers $Headers | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
Write-host "$Result"
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add your Powershell code too. The error message says that `$date` is in invalid format. To debug, one needs to see what's in that variable too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use single quotes in your code, you'll pass the exact string, so the variables won't be 'converted' to their values.

Using that code:

```
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/measures/search_history?component=AP-EASI&metrics=coverage&from=$date&to=$date' -Headers $Headers
```

You access that URL:

```
https://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/measures/search_history?component=AP-EASI&metrics=coverage&from=$date&to=$date
```

What you should do is to use double quotes `"` so that variables are evaluated. The code you should use is:

```
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/measures/search_history?component=AP-EASI&metrics=coverage&from=$date&to=$date" -Headers $Headers
```

Assuming your `$Headers` value is correct, that should work.

---

**NOTE**: As vonPryz suggested in comments, please always remember to post your code as it's crucial to troubleshooting (as you can see in that case).